# Duplicity backup restore to the same system or other system had issue

Tags: backup, duplicity

I have installed the duplicity on centos-7 and I was able to encrypt the data and able to restored the same on other server.

```
duplicity --encrypt-key='12005FB81112' etc.gz scp://xyz@104.111.108.101/backup/
```

when I restored the backup I was able to restored the same in original server.

```
duplicity restore  --ssh-askpass scp://niraj@104.130.198.8/backup/ /backup
```

But the same command when I run on other server it gives following error so how to restored on other server ??????

```
GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: directory `/home/niraj/.gnupg' created
gpg: new configuration file `/home/niraj/.gnupg/gpg.conf' created
gpg: WARNING: options in `/home/niraj/.gnupg/gpg.conf' are not yet active during this run
gpg: keyring `/home/niraj/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/home/niraj/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID 4FA0BF28
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
===== End GnuPG log =====
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to do it via **ftp instead scp** procol. And without encryption. Example with full backup:

```
duplicity full <your-folder-or-file> ftp://user:pass@<host>/backup-folder/
```

It worked for me. Also I'm trying to do if via sftp or scp but I don't find my issue yet. So is a provisional answer.